# Need advice concering forecasting next year based on irregular time-series - UPDATED

Tags: r, time-series, self-study, forecasting

I need your advice with regards to the following inquiry: 
"Based on your observations, what could you say about the **load** for the same months in year 2019?"

```
data.frame':    683 obs. of  10 variables:
$ Route       : chr  "A" "B" "A" "A" ...
$ FlightNumber: int  770 279 128 235 434 543 556 663 770 279 ...
$ Capacity    : int  375 345 375 375 375 375 375 375 375 345 ...
$ Booked      : int  379 314 374 379 373 377 379 378 379 294 ...
$ DDate       : Date, format: "2018-05-01" "2018-05-01" "2018-05-02" "2018-05-03" ...
$ Year        : num  2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 ...
$ Month       : num  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
$ Day         : int  1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 8 ...
$ Hour        : int  12 20 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 20 ...
$ load        : num  1.011 0.91 0.997 1.011 0.995 ...

  Route  FlightNumber  Capacity  Booked  DDate  Year   Month Day Hour load(=Booked/Capacity)
1 A               770      375    379 2018-05-01 2018     5   1   12    1.0106667
2 B               279      345    314 2018-05-01 2018     5   1   20    0.9101449
3 A               128      375    374 2018-05-02 2018     5   2   12    0.9973333
4 A               235      375    379 2018-05-03 2018     5   3   12    1.0106667
5 A               434      375    373 2018-05-04 2018     5   4   12    0.9946667
6 A               543      375    377 2018-05-05 2018     5   5   12    1.0053333
```

If I plot the data, they look like this:

[image: geom_point]

**UPDATE**: I ended up doing the following:

```
ts_CY <- ts(dat_ts_CY$load, start = c(2017,5), end = c(2018,11), frequency = 1*12)
fit_CY <- auto.arima(ts_CY)
          summary(fit_CY)
          predict_CY <- forecast(fit_CY,n=1)
          plot(predict_CY)
```

[image: Predicted outcome image]

**UPDATE 11/01/2018**

```
 #According to the output, turns out by grouping I have 6 months (May to  Oct) -_-' 
  test_agg  <- test %>% group_by(Route, Year, Month) %>% filter(Route == "CCCYYY") %>% 
               summarize(load = mean(load, na.rm = TRUE))
  agg_CY_ts <- ts(test_agg$load, start = c(2017,5), end = c(2018,10), frequency = 2*6)
  fit_agg_CY <- auto.arima(agg_CY_ts)
  forecast(fit_agg_CY,h=2*6) %>% plot()
```

[image: New output]

This is not exactly my area of expertise, but **does the prediction seem correct** since the prediction looks rather "simple/flat".

Would you have done the analysis applying different methods? If so, could please elaborate ...

Answer (score 0):

Since this looks like a homework question, I will nudge in the right direction rather than answering outright. There are many ways to create or represent timeseries data in R, so I will stick to the most basic one. The R `ts` function takes in a vector, not a dataframe. To convert your data into a timeseries using this function you would need to filter to the relevant `Route` and look at the `load` column as a vector.

Since the question asks about monthly predictions, you may want to aggregate to the month level. A package such as `xts` can simplify this, but I would recommend doing it manually for the first few times. Keep in mind what 'load' would even mean in an aggregated sense.

```
v <- [load vector for route A]
f <- [number of observations per year]
p <- [period of first observation]
routeA.ts <- ts(v, start = c(2017,p), frequency = f)
```

Note that since you do not pass dates into the `ts` function, it assumes that there is no missingness in the data. Since these routes appear to run May - Nov, You will need to think about how to handle this based on modifying `v`, `f`, and/or `p`.

Once you have a timeseries object, you should be able to leverage the `forecast` library.

Comment: Hey Michael, I was hoping you could input some additional feedback now that I’ve “completed” the task.  Did I get something wrong? If so, could you please elaborate as I personally want to better understand the logic behind the task. P.s. I tried liking your answer but I don’t have enough credentials for it to be reflected 

Comment: Hey Exequiel. You would first need to aggregate the data so that you have one record per month. I like `tidyverse` package for this (it comes with a lot of plotting and data management tools, you really only need dplyr and tidyr). Once you aggregate to Month and Year, convert your data to a timeseries with a period of 7, since you only have observations for 7 months of the year (this isn't a perfect handling due to non-constant time difference between observations, but a starting point). Then your remaining code should work.

Comment: Thanks for replying back ^.^ In the frequency section, should it be 2*6 since there are two periods of 6 months (May to Oct after all) because if I leave it at 6 the time series reports as ending in 2019/04. I've pasted the CODES at the bottom section of the question page for clarity sake :p